# Why not working my modal correctly?

Tags: php, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have the following form code:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
   <form action="/admin/menuContent.php?id=<?php echo $menuId ?>" method="post">
       //few inputs...
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input id="editButton" class="btn btn-success editButton" type="submit" value="Save" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" role="button">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <a href="/admin/menus.php" class="btn btn-default cancelButton">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And my problem is that after click save button the modal appears but just for a second or less, what can be a problem? Thanks for helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

that error come just because of url passed in form action.try to figure out that.whether you have passed correct url or not.
i have tried this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">  </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;  </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>

        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input id="editButton" class="btn btn-success editButton"  type="submit" value="Save" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  role="button">
        </div>
        </div>
    
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not trigger form submit and modal with a single submit button.When you trigger the submit button the modal disappears and direct to **menuContent.php**.You should use some client side programs to pass the parameters into the php.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the save button, the form was submitted. 
So this goes to action page. (action="/admin/menuContent.php?id=")

Please refer this and solve your problem: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp